# What compiler flags are libstdc++ compiled with?

Tags: c++

I'm specifically using mingw-builds 6.2, but the answer could apply to any compiler.

When linking against the libstdc++.dll that comes with my compiler, what flags are typically used to compile it? Would I see some performance increase if I were to build it myself with `-O3`?

Comment: 1) you don't need to know. 2) maybe, but they will most likely be trivial.

Comment: Yes, they deliberately make it slow so you can fix it with a simple flag... /sarcasm.

Comment: `-Ox` compiler flags rarely have the performance increase that you seek. Bad performance is more often from design flaws than forgetting to inline or compress a tight loop.  First rule of performance optimization: Go profile your code and figure out where it's slow before you start trying to throw optimizations at it.

Comment: As has been said,  you don't need to know or do it,  and if you are paranoid about it,  go to your compiler implementation/distribution specific docs.